# Face recognition ANN project by Neurpoh Studio gets "No enum constant error"

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition, turkish, neuroph

I working on a [face recognition project](http://neuroph.sourceforge.net/tutorials/FaceRecognition/FaceRecognitionUsingNeuralNetwork.html) to learn Artifical Neural Network logic.

When I was applying steps, I got the following error:

> **No enum constant org.neuroph.util.TransferFunctionType.SİGMOİD** error at Step 3.1 that setting multi-layer perception layer step.

[image: picture of error message]

I don't understand what does it mean. 
we suspect "SİGMOİD" word that in error message with [@Melebius](https://stackoverflow.com/users/711006/melebius). It consists Turkish character(İ). I use windows 10 on Turkish however language of  Neuroph studio is English.
I couldn't find any resolution and resolve this error.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: There are `İ` letters which do not appear usually, I’ve only met them in Turkish. Isn’t it a typo?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am from Turkey, but I use in English the Neuroph Studio. I don't know why "SİGMOİD" is Turkish, maybe from windows usage language. I also don't know how to change it to English :)

Comment: So please try to correct it to `SIGMOID` to check if it’s the cause. If it helps, you can [edit] your question to make clear you want to help with writing English on Turkish Windows.

Comment: When i select tanh as Transfer Function, it works. Promlem is upper i characters. I changed Windows writing language to English, but it did not work again. I got same error.

Comment: That’s interesting information, you should really include it in the question by [edit]ing it. You should also consider using appropriate tags and title, so your question comes to the right audience. I’m suggesting [tag:turkish], [tag:windows].